# Arithmetic sums of Marczewski null sets

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, inner-models

First, recall the Marczewski ideal, called $s^0$: a set $A$ of reals is in $s^0$ iff for every perfect set $P$ there is some perfect $P' \subset P$ such that $P' \cap A = \emptyset$. Secondly, by way of notation, if $A \subset {\mathbb R}$, then  $A + A$ denotes $\{ x+y \; \colon \, x, y \in A \}$. Question:

(1) Can you have $A \in s^0$ such that $A+A={\mathbb R}$? Or such that $A + A + \ldots + A = {\mathbb R}$?

If $M$ is an inner model of $V$, $M \models {\sf CH}$ and ${\mathbb R} \setminus M \not= \emptyset$, then by Groszek-Slaman, ${\mathbb R} \cap M \in s^0$. If $M_1$, $\ldots$, $M_n$ are finitely many such inner models (i.e., $M_i \models {\sf CH}$ and ${\mathbb R} \setminus M_i \not= \emptyset$ for all $i$), then $A = \bigcup \{ {\mathbb R} \cap M_i \; \colon \, 1 \leq i \leq n \}$ is in $s^0$. Question:

(2) Can you have an $A$ like in the previous paragraph such that $A+A={\mathbb R}$? Or such that $A + A + \ldots + A = {\mathbb R}$?

Trivially, an affirmative answer to (2) gives an affirmative answer to (1).

Comment: In (1), I guess you intend that $A\in s^0$?

Comment: Yep, sure, thx, I repaired it.

Comment: Under CH, there is a Lusin set $L \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $L + L = \mathbb{R}$. Since $L$ meets every closed nowhere dense set on a countable set, it is Marczewski-null. There is a ZFC construction of a Marczewski-null Hamel basis in A. Miller and S. Popvassilev, Vitali sets and Hamel bases that are Marczewski measurable, Fund. Math. 166(2000), 269-279. Looking at their proof, I think it should also give a Marczewski-null set $A$ such that $A + A + A + A = \mathbb{R}$ -- Perhaps you can bring it down to two terms.

Comment: Great, this gives an answer to (1) like I had it in mind. (2) is probably a different issue. What e.g. if $V=L[c]$, $c$ a Cohen real over $L$?